# SDK Tools not opening in android studio

Tags: android-studio

SDK tools is not opening in SDK manager in android studio. I tried to click on SDK tools and SDK update sites and even show package details but nothing is opening.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check :

- Is Android SDK Location correctly set ? (Typical value on a Linux host is `/home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk`)
- Have you full access to this directory (both read/write) ?
- Check if you have an error message in the Android Studio log file (Typically located under /home/USERNAME/.AndroidStudio2.2/system/log/idea.log

You can also try to *Launch Standalone SDK Manager* (link at the bottom of the window) and see what happens.